# Using leaflet.js trying to use L.vectorGrid.protobuf to display vector tiles on top of Leisure EPSG:27700 OS Map

Tags: leaflet, vector-tiles

I'm using the following code to bring an OS Leisure Map into Leaflet

```
var apiKey = 'INSERT_API_KEY_HERE';

var serviceUrl = 'https://api.os.uk/maps/raster/v1/zxy';

// Setup the EPSG:27700 (British National Grid) projection.
var crs = new L.Proj.CRS('EPSG:27700', '+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +towgs84=446.448,-125.157,542.06,0.15,0.247,0.842,-20.489 +units=m +no_defs', {
    resolutions: [ 896.0, 448.0, 224.0, 112.0, 56.0, 28.0, 14.0, 7.0, 3.5, 1.75 ],
    origin: [ -238375.0, 1376256.0 ]
});

// Transform coordinates.
var transformCoords = function(arr) {
    return proj4('EPSG:27700', 'EPSG:4326', arr).reverse();
};

// Initialize the map.
var mapOptions = {
    crs: crs,
    minZoom: 0,
    maxZoom: 9,
    center: transformCoords([ 337297, 503695 ]),
    zoom: 7,
    maxBounds: [
        transformCoords([ -238375.0, 0.0 ]),
        transformCoords([ 900000.0, 1376256.0 ])
    ],
    attributionControl: false
};

var map = L.map('map', mapOptions);

// Load and display ZXY tile layer on the map.
var basemap = L.tileLayer(serviceUrl + '/Leisure_27700/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?key=' + apiKey).addTo(map);
```

This works fine.

But when I try to use `L.vectorGrid.protobuf` to bring in my vector tiles, they are rendered in the wrong location.

```
var openMapTilesUrl = "https://map-tests.local/tileserver/countyborders/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf";

            var mapboxVectorTileOptions = {
                interactive: true,

            var trgovine = L.vectorGrid.protobuf(openMapTilesUrl, mapboxVectorTileOptions).on('click', function(e) { // The .on method attaches an event handler
                console.log(e.layer);
                L.popup()
                    .setContent(e.layer.properties.name)
                //                  .setContent(JSON.stringify(e.layer))
                // .setLatLng(e.latlng)
                //.openOn(map)
            }).addTo(map);
```

The result.
[image]

My vector tiles were created with Tippencanoe and I think I'm right in saying that they are EPSG:3857.

Is the fact that the projections are different is what causing the vector tiles to be in the wrong place?

I'm totally new to maps.

Comment: You are out of luck here. Leaflet supports only one CRS per map. `L.vectorGrid.protobuf` layer has fixed CRS `EPSG:3857`, so you cannot mix it with your base raster layer, which has CRS `EPSG:27700`.

Comment: Dam. Well that sucks. Thanks for the reply. Does Mapbox GLJS also have the same restrictions?

Comment: Yes. Only OpenLayers does on-the-fly reprojection of raster layers.